# Tkinter get() function is not returning anything

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a program using a tkinter GUI to calculate a few things. My get() function isn't working and I'm not sure why

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
root = Tk()

v = 0
l = 0
w = 0
t1 = 0
t0 = 0

label1 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for length (mm) :").grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
length = Entry(root).grid(row = 0, column = 2)

label2 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for volume (mm^2) :").grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
volume = Entry(root).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label3 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for the thickness of the cylinder (mm) :").grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
thickness = Entry(root).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

label4 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for starting temperature (K) :").grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
st_T = Entry(root).grid(row = 3, column = 2)

label5 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for finishing temperature (K) :").grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
end_T = Entry(root).grid(row = 4, column = 2)

def save():
    v = volume.get()
    l = length.get()
    w = thickness.get()
    t0 = st_T.get()
    t1 = end_T.get()

    global values 
    values = [v, l, w, t1, t0]

answer = StringVar()
labelans = Label(root, textvariable = answer).grid(columnspan = 3,)
answer.set("Answer = ")

def area_circle():
    global answer
    answer =  v / l
    print(answer)

Button(root, text = "Submit", command = save()).grid(row = 6, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Obviously there are variables i'm not using yet but im trying to get the first part right first.

For v the error displayed is:
  Message='NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: This is a duplicate of two questions. The other one it's a duplicate of is http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432

Answer (score 1):

> The Grid geometry manager puts the widgets in a 2-dimensional table.
>   The master widget is split into a number of rows and columns, and each
>   “cell” in the resulting table can hold a widget.
>
> **What is important Grid() is returning NoneValue**
>
> if you are doing like:
>
> ```
> length = Entry(root).grid(row = 0, column = 2)
> ```
>
> in your variable length you will have NoneValue
>
> you should do it like :
>
> ```
> length = Entry(root)
> length.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
> ```

your code:

```
label1 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for length (mm) :")
label1.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
length = Entry(root)
length.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

label2 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for volume (mm^2) :")
label2.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
volume = Entry(root)
volume.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label3 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for the thickness of the cylinder (mm) :")
label3.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
thickness = Entry(root)
thickness.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

label4 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for starting temperature (K) :")
label4.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
st_T = Entry(root)
st_T.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

label5 = Label(root, text = "Enter value for finishing temperature (K) :")
label5.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = "E")
end_T = Entry(root)
end_T.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

def save():
    v = volume.get()
    l = length.get()
    w = thickness.get()
    t0 = st_T.get()
    t1 = end_T.get()

    global values
    values = [v, l, w, t1, t0]

answer = StringVar()
labelans = Label(root, textvariable = answer).grid(columnspan = 3,)
answer.set("Answer = ")

def area_circle():
    global answer
    answer =  v / l
    print(answer)

Button(root, text = "Submit", command = save()).grid(row = 6, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `command` argument should be a callback, not the actual call:

```
Button(root, text="Submit", command=save).grid(row=6, column=0)
```

Comment: i changed it but it still returns the NoneType error as before

Comment: Just delete those parentheses on save, it will work.

Comment: Like I said, i removed the parentheses and the NoneType error remained

Comment: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/oJ1oTyT)

Comment: As @ncica pointed out, and what you haven't mentioned, after solving initial bug another is now cleary exposed after actually clicking the button. Please refer to his answer for a solution.